# Uint8 - Missing Type specifier

Tags: c++, sdl, undefined-reference, uint

I'm trying to write a singleton class to hold the state of inputs from the user (mouse/keyboard data). The SDL API returns keyboard data as Uint8 pointer array, however, why I try to create the Uint8 pointer, I get these errors at the line w/ the uint8:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

I've used Uint8 as a data type without defining it before, so I'm not sure what is causing the issue here. Here is my code:

```c
class InputState {
public:

    InputState()
    {};
    ~InputState()
    {};


    static InputState *getInputState(void)
    {
        static InputState *state = new InputState();

        return state;
    };

public:
    Uint8 *keys;

    struct MouseState
    {
        int LeftButtonDown;
        int RightButtonDown;
        int MiddleButtonDown;

        int x;
        int y;

        MouseState ()
        {
            LeftButtonDown = 0;
            RightButtonDown = 0;
            MiddleButtonDown = 0;

            x = 0;
            y = 0;
        }
    };

    MouseState *mouseState;
};
```

Comment: Have you included _whatever SDL header_ that defines `Uint8`? And please please please don't call it a _keyword_...

Comment: Appologies, I've edited the question. I'm not sure where the definition comes from, SDL or otherwise. As a check though, I went back to an old file, that uses Uint8 w/o error, and included all the same header files, without any luck.

Comment: Side note: with a singleton class, you should make its constructor private. Second [make sure you really want a singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Drawbacks)

Comment: Just so anybody doesn't get confused, it's `Uint8` not `Unit8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `Uint8` is a typedef that is defined in one of the `SDL` header. If you want to use it, you need to include the `SDL.h` header in your file.

```
// You need this include if you want to use SDL typedefs
#include <SDL.h>

class InputState {
public:

    InputState()
    {};
    ~InputState()
    {};

    // ...

public:
    Uint8 *keys;

    // ...
};
```

Comment: Thats did it. I was under the impression the Uints were default data types. Thanks.

Comment: @Donutfiend84, `uint8_t` is part of `<cstdint>`.